# Communication between 2 Flex/Flash apps on the same webpage

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex4, externalinterface

What's the best way to communicate between 2 Flex/Flash apps on the same webpage?  I need a 3rd party Flash app to call a function on my Flex 4 app (they are ready to customize their 3rd party app how I specify).  I use `ExternalInterface.call("javascript_function", arguments)` extensively.  I know there's a bridge to go from Javascript to Actionscript as well.  So I guess I could go from their flash app -> javascript function -> flex bridge -> my flex app.  Do I have to go through javascript?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

You can look at LocalConnection, but if the other app is really a third party, it might make more sense to use Javascript as the bridge (As you don't really have full control over the other app).

LocalConnection is certainly nicer and cleaner than using Javascript, but I'm always worried about giving a third party access to the internals of my app.

Comment: You only expose the methods in the LocalConnections client object - just don;t set the client to the application itself and you don't have to worry about exposing your app internals. You can also set a domain policy on the localconnection to prevent malicious 3rd party access.

Comment: Yeah I think my worry is much more paranoia than any real concern. Although if you do control the javascript then it can help ease the integration tests between the two parties (Rather than sending binaries back and forth for testing). As you can easily see that each party is sending and receiving the correct data. It can be helpful if the communication with the external party is pretty poor.

Comment: I think you could also get the 3rd party app to export their data to a local XML file in an assets folder (on web server side where both apps reside), and your app could use a URLLoader to read this.

Comment: LocalConnection was what I was looking for, thanks.  But now I'm thinking a JavaScript bridge makes more sense because this is a 3rd party app and I may not have the ability to make changes in the future.  I'd like the flexibility javascript would allow for (maybe changing the app to Javascript).